# Kendo dropdownlist not working in android webview

Tags: android, kendo-ui

I have kendo dropdown list in my website, it working fine when trying in mobile browser, but when I am trying to choose element from this dropdown list in webview it is not working.

Comment: please add additional info to your question, from what you have provided so far, you won't find an answer or help here. always consider "if i read my own question, would i be able to understand it"